# Should I escape the html for the settings field created with add_settings_field?

Tags: settings-api, escaping

I am using a class that handles the output of WP settings fields.
This class uses the function "add_settings_field" which receives as a "callback" parameter the name of the function that prints the html of the field.

```
add_settings_field( $args["name"], $args["label"], $args["callback"], $args["menu_slug"], $args["section"], $args );
```

If I escape the html, instead of the fields the html is printed as a string (see screenshot).

```
public function callback_text( $args ) {
        $value       = $this->get_option( $args['id'], $args['option'], $args['std'] );
        $size        = isset( $args['size'] ) && !is_null( $args['size'] ) ? $args['size'] : 'regular';
        $type        = isset( $args['type'] ) ? $args['type'] : 'text';
        $placeholder = empty( $args['placeholder'] ) ? '' : ' placeholder="' . $args['placeholder'] . '"';
        $required = $args["required"] ? 'required' : '';

        $html        = sprintf(
            '<input type="%1$s" class="%2$s-text" id="%4$s" name="%3$s" value="%5$s"%6$s %7$s/>',
            esc_attr( $type ),
            esc_attr( $size ),
            esc_attr( $args['name'] ),
            esc_attr( $args['id'] ),
            esc_attr( $value ),
            $placeholder,
            esc_attr( $required )
        );
        $html       .= $this->get_field_description( $args );

        echo esc_html( $html );
    }
```

[image: esc_html return string]

How can I escape the html correctly?
Should I escape the html for the settings field in this case?

Thanks,
Giulia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t need to escape HTML you wrote. You wrote it and it’s hard-coded a certain way so there’s no way for it to be replaced by malicious or broken code. You only need to escape the external values that are being inserted into the attributes and you’ve done that.

Also, note that the purpose of `esc_html()` is to escape a value so that it is not treated as HTML.

Comment: Thanks Jacob that was what I thought but I wasn't sure.

Comment: @GiuliaRabita-Metup Jacob is right, but I still wanted to jump in to commend you for being thorough with escaping! Good way to start your WordPress journey on WPSE!

Comment: I note that some plugin reviewers want you to escape everything, including hard-coded html, or a variable that contains hard-coded html. (Having that issue right now with a new plugin I am trying to get through review.)